# Issue Accessing Environment Variables Set in Systemd Service File in Next.js on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, next.js, environment-variables, systemd, production-environment

I'm encountering an issue with my Next.js application hosted on an Ubuntu server. I have set some environment variables within my systemd service file:

`[Service] ... Environment=NEXT_PUBLIC_SYSTEM_ENV=Test Environment=NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=https://agrohub-api.lemon.do ...`

However, when trying to access these variables in my Next.js app using process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SYSTEM_ENV and process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL, I'm getting undefined.

I've tried reloading systemd and restarting the service, verifying the environment of the running process, and ensuring there's no conflict within any configuration files. Yet, the issue persists.

Has anyone faced a similar issue or can offer any insights on how to resolve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!